# Unable to log events using Spring and Clojure

Tags: spring, clojure, log4j

I am creating a web application using Spring framework and Clojure. To do so I have created a class that extends `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` and then registered a couple of handlers as shown:

```
(:use [clojure.tools.logging :only (debug info error)])
(defn -post-init [this]
  (do
    (.registerHandler this "/services.html"
       (proxy [AbstractController] []
         (handleRequestInternal [request response]
           (info "Hello everyone")
           (ModelAndView. "services" "lof" "List of services")
          )
         )
      )....
```

All events generated by the Spring framework are logged in the log file (configured with a log4j.properties in the class path) but none of the application messages are logged.

Comment: not related to the question, but the close paren on a newline is rather unusual (others would call it non idiomatic)

Comment: Have you looked at compojure and hiccup? Because if you're using clojure I doubt spring is best way...

Comment: code doesn't look complete: where is rest of ns declaration? And are you sure the code is being called?